# How can I run post-package commands in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, solution-package, packaging

When building my SharePoint projects with Visual Studio 2010, I prefer to use Package instead of Deploy. Even if I plan to deploy the wsp on my computer, I want to use my PowerShell scripts in order to test the deployment process for when I eventually deploy to a server that does not have Visual Studio.

If I go to the project properties page, I can add commands to either Build Events > Post-event command line or SharePoint > Pre-deployment Command Line. The former is too early because the solution package hasn't been built. The latter might work, but is there a way to quietly exit or cancel the deployment without receiving a "Build failed" error? If not, is there a way to edit the csproj file so that I can run a post-package command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried creating a new deployment configuration on the SharePoint tab with **Run Pre-Deployment Command** as the only step and then putting your post-package command(s) in the **Pre-deployment command line** box?

...and make sure that you set **Active Deployment Configuration** to your newly created deployment configuration.

Comment: Perfect! I totally overlooked that section. That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks!